# Валидация и маска для поля ввода телефона на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, form, input

Есть такая вот запись.
Она проверяет на валидность заполнение поля с email.
Если не ошибаюсь это называется паттерн:

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,8})+$/
```

Подскажите, есть подобная запись, которая будет проверять поле ввода телефона?
А именно, что бы был ввод именно цифр в формате `+7 (999) 999-99-99`

Спасибо

Comment: Вы можете написать регулярное выражение (так это называется) для проверки, что введённая пользователем строка состоит из цифр. Но вы можете использовать [input type="tel"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/tel) для поля ввода телефона. Помните, что вся валидация на фронте нужна только для удобства пользователя (интернет-хулиган запросто пришлёт вам номер 112).

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('.tel'), function(input) {
    var keyCode;
    function mask(event) {
        event.keyCode && (keyCode = event.keyCode);
        var pos = this.selectionStart;
        if (pos < 3) event.preventDefault();
        var matrix = "+7 (___)-___-__-__",
            i = 0,
            def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
            val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ""),
            new_value = matrix.replace(/[_\d]/g, function(a) {
                return i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) || def.charAt(i) : a
            });
        i = new_value.indexOf("_");
        if (i != -1) {
            i < 5 && (i = 3);
            new_value = new_value.slice(0, i)
        }
        var reg = matrix.substr(0, this.value.length).replace(/_+/g,
            function(a) {
                return "\\d{1," + a.length + "}"
            }).replace(/[+()]/g, "\\$&");
        reg = new RegExp("^" + reg + "$");
        if (!reg.test(this.value) || this.value.length < 5 || keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) this.value = new_value;
        if (event.type == "blur" && this.value.length < 5)  this.value = ""
    }

    input.addEventListener("input", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("keydown", mask, false)

  });

});
```

```html
<input value="" class="tel">
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А короче никак?)

Comment: @ElJeko ставьте тогда jquery inputmask
а так можно конечно покороче, ну а что там +-50 символов это же пару секунд)

Comment: Дело не количестве, а в навыке) Я откровенно говоря не понимаю как это использовать. Нашел вариант с проверкой поля email и думал, что есть такая же проверка только с телефоном.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gG4rtJ/1